# Acces VPN over Windows network management instead of OpenVPN client

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, openvpn

I am running openVPN on my Linux server and use openVPN Windows client to connect to it - everything is working fine.
Now I was wondering if I can setup the VPN connection through Windows' network management. I know it must be possible as I can connect to my university's VPN doing so (it's listed under connections).

However, when I tried setting it up I couldn't get it to work. Mainly because I didn't know what to do with the certificates (ca.crt, client.crt, client.key). Apart from that Windows always asks for a password which I didn't set on the server since the authentification is done through the certificates.

Any idea if my scenario is even possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible as native Windows network management does not support OpenVPN. It supports PPTP and maybe some other types of private networking protocols.

Answer (score 3):

Windows supports SSTP, L2TP, and PPTP, as well as DirectAccess (with Enterprise SKUs). No OpenVPN support here, you need to use the OpenVPN client for that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that your university is actually using OpenVPN? In fact Windows does **not** support OpenVPN out of the box (some Linux OS like Ubuntu got built-in OpenVPN support in the network manager).

So you can not establish a OpenVPN connection without the oVPN client. A possible workaround would be placing another pc/server (or a cheap router running openwrt) in front of the windows machine ... But that's a bit off topic.